# How scroll a canvas up? (Writing chat in Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, scroll, canvas

I'm writing a chat client using Flex.

The basis for the chat window is a canvas.  I've got that showing, but how do I make it scroll up?  I want to clip the window so only the last 15 lines are shown.

This doesn't appear to be working (nothing moves):

```
<mx:Canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="3000" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="on" creationComplete="myinit()">
    <mx:Label text="HI" x="10" y="100"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Shouldn't this scroll the canvas every time it's called?:

canvas.verticalScrollPosition += 10;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the verticalScrollPosition of the parent container. Such as

```
<mx:Canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"
           horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="on"
           creationComplete="myinit()">
    <mx:Canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="3000">
        <mx:Label text="HI" x="10" y="100"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Now

```
canvas.verticalScrollPosition += 10;
```

should work.

Comment: Ah, duh!  That makes sense.  One problem, though, when I try to add an 'id' attribute to the outer canvas I get this:

id attribute is not allowed on the root tag of a component.

How do you get around that?  Thanks for your help.